# Post Request works from Postman but not from cURL

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to upload a multipart file to a server. However, the post request works fine when tried with Postman but returns a java exception when called using cURL

> Service below returns java exception.

Code Section :

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:49901/capital/rest/v1/projects/UID4d99e5-1669f58e3f2-e6726ae9eef110442b36e368eca820c9/harnessdesigns/UID56a429-1669a3c70b3-e6726ae9eef110442b36e368eca820c9/attacheddata \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=node0rhpkec0q1a521nz49bq6c0dy93.node0' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F attachment=@/C:/Users/cabpq1/Desktop/CapitalData/ImportSpliceBundleInfoFile.json \
  -F 'customdata={"attributes":{"name":"AttachedData4","type":"type1","key":"key"}}'
```

Response Section :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /capital/rest/v1/projects/UID4d99e5-1669f58e3f2-e6726ae9eef110442b36e368eca820c9/harnessdesigns/UID56a429-1669a3c70b3-e6726ae9eef110442b36e368eca820c9/attacheddata. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)`enter code here`
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
```

Answer (score 1):

## client side

First you've used curl's `-F` option that performs a multi-part form-post and yet you set a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That seems highly unlikely to be right.

Then you've set `content-type:` *again* and this time to "multipart/form-data;" (which is default for `-F`  already).

Are you *sure* you need to fiddle with the boundary string like that? It is unusual.

You're passing on hard-coded cookie contents, which rarely is what the server side expects.

(`-X POST` should *not* be used if you want a POST and use -d or -F)

## server side

It's a 500 response code, that's a server error that the client really shouldn't be able to trigger...

## debug this

Add `--trace-ascii logfile.txt` to the curl command line and you'll get to see *exactly* what curl sends (and receives) and then you can compare that with the working version and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your response clearly says timeout.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
```

In Postman check the config

> Request Timeout in ms (0 for infinity): Set how long the app should wait for a response before saying that the server isn’t responding. A value of 0 indicates infinity - Postman will wait for a response forever.

Same thing can be achieved with curl , curl has two options: --connect-timeout and --max-time

From the curl man page

> **--connect-timeout** 
>       Maximum  time  in  seconds  that you allow the connection to the
>       server to take.
>
> **-m, --max-time** 
>       Maximum  time  in  seconds that you allow the whole operation to
>       take.